# KLinkStatus does not search in depth

Tags: testing, automated-tests

I have an issue with KLinkStatus, it does not search for broken links in depth, it just stops after searching the links on a single page. In the search options i have set it to be Unlimited.
Does anybody know what could cause this ?

I use Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, and KLinkStatus is a KDE application, could that be the cause for it ?

Any answerer would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Radu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the info you gave me in private, the issue was that a redirection was happening: google.com to google.ro. This last domain is seen as a different one by the application so it doesn't go deeper on this external page. If one puts google.ro directly on KLinkStatus it crawls as expected.

Kind regards, Paulo

Comment: I can confirm that this solved my problem. Thank you Paulo !!

Answer (score 0):

I'm testing with Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS and it's crawling as expected. Did you test with other pages (e.g. google.com) to check if that behaviour is caused by something specific of that site?

The fact that it is a KDE application doesn't matter, it just means that it uses Qt and KDE libraries underneath.

Cheers, Paulo

Comment: I did try with other sites but the outcome is the same, after searching only one page, it stops.

Comment: Radu, please write me a private message at pmouraguedes at gmail.com, so we can debug it. Thanks

Comment: I've sent you an email, as requested.